Subtract minutes from Date by using Calendar fails
I'm writing an app that must find some time for alarm (from Date object), and then should subtract several hours and minutes (by using Calendar object) selected by the user (interval, several hours and minutes before the selected time).
I tried to do that, and the program subtract the hours (intervalHours below) successfully, but when I'm trying to subtract the minutes (intervalMinutes below), the program shows wrong time.
Here is the code (this.realAlarmTime is the selected time, of Date type):
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(this.realAlarmTime);
            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, -(this.intervalHours));
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -(this.intervalMinutes));
            this.realAlarmTime = calendar.getTime();

For example, when the program selected the time "15:47", and the interval is 1 MINUTE, the program shows "16:59", while subtracting 1 HOUR shows "14:57"..
is there something wrong in this program, or maybe the function calrnder.add is not correct for this target?
I tried other ways, but did not come up with a solution.

java.time has been available for 10 years (since java 8). Use it. Don't use Calendar.

What is your timezone?

@Sören the ability to use java.time in android has only been around since android O which was 2017

even using the old classes (and feeling a little bad doing so) unable to reproduce: https://ideone.com/atyGLr  -- I had to complete the code, maybe better include a [mre]

Why are you subtracting hours and minutes from an alarm time? Is this a ham-fisted attempt at adjusting for a time zone? If so, post a question on the actual original problem. Your current Question is confusing and unfocused.

The behaviour you describe sounds weird. A [mre], please?

I cannot reproduce. In your first case (1 minute) I get Thu Jun 06 15:46:00 CEST 2024. With 1 hour instead I get Thu Jun 06 14:47:00 CEST 2024. I suspect that your problem lies somewhere else outside the code you are showing us. I repeat asking for a [mre], please.

@tyczj That may have been true once, but for many years it hasn’t been. If you are coding for Android versions before Oreo (API level 26), you may either use core library desugaring or ThreeTenABP.

subtract the hours (...) successfully ... selected the time "15:47", ... subtracting 1 HOUR shows "14:57".. How does that count as "successful"? Only 50 minutes seem to have been subtracted?

@BasilBourque Nothing I know, obviously, possibly the user specifies how long time before an event s/he wants an alarm. (We are only told: that selected by the user (interval, several hours and minutes before the selected time).)

I believe that this is how you should do it -- see it run online.

Assuming you can not change the input Date you can use the current time classes instead of Calendar but the recommendation would be to get rid of Date too. It seems from your question that you might be having an issue related to handling of the timezone. For example if you are assuming the timezone is the local one but the result is in UTC that could be reason the result is not what you are expecting. There is not enough information to be sure.
Example using ZonedDateTime instead of Calendar/Date classes to perform similar calculations:
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int intervalHours=1;
        int intervalMinutes=1;
        ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(2024, 6, 5, 15, 47, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        
        dateTime = dateTime.minusHours(intervalHours);
        dateTime = dateTime.minusMinutes(intervalMinutes);
        System.out.println("Updated date = " + dateTime);
    }
}

Output:
Updated date = 2024-06-05T14:46-04:00[America/New_York]

If you want to use the timezone that your system is using you can use ZoneId.systemDefault() instead of ZoneId.of(). See ZoneId documentation for more options.

LocalDateTime is exactly the wrong class to use here. You are ignoring any temporal anomalies that may be present in the relevant time zone. So your subtractions may result in incorrect date-time values.

After I wrote the answer I started to think that maybe the original issue is more related to timezone offset but there is not enough detail in the question to be sure.

I updated the example to use only ZonedDateTime and mentioned the possible issue.

ZonedDateTime is the wrong class here. You explicitly pass an offset rather than a time zone. So use OffsetDateTime rather than ZonedDateTime. Furthermore, this Question is unfocused, and seemingly unintelligible. Posting an Answer to an unknowable Question is not really helpful.

@BasilBourque Very possibly the user wants her/his own time, if so we can use a real time zone (like America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires) and ZonedDateTime and not UTC+01:00, which isn’t a real time zone. I still see the answer as having potential to be helpful.

@Anonymous Sure, which is why I made the comment, so the author can make the example more fitting. It is improved, but still misleading to the novice learning about date-time handling.

Would not be simpler to use ZoneId.systemDefault() for the example and mention alternatives?
